# pydantic module check the variables only in init

Tags: python, pydantic

pydantic module check the variables only in init

pip install pydantic

Example

```
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Glass:
    capacity_volume : float
    occupied_volume : float

glass = Glass(300, 100)       # OK int to float
print(glass) # Glass(capacity_volume=500.0, occupied_volume=0.0)

glass = Glass(300.0, 100.0)   # OK 
print(glass) # Glass(capacity_volume=500.0, occupied_volume=0.0)

glass = Glass('300', '100')   # OK str to float    
print(glass) # Glass(capacity_volume=500.0, occupied_volume=0.0)

glass.capacity_volume = '300' 
print(glass) # Glass(capacity_volume='300', occupied_volume=0.0)
```

Is it possible to check the types of variables if they are set?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, entirely possible if I understand you correctly:

```py
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

class Config:
    validate_assignment = True

@dataclass(config=Config)
class Glass:
    capacity_volume: float
    occupied_volume: float

glass = Glass('300', '100')
print(glass)  
#> Glass(capacity_volume=300.0, occupied_volume=100.0)

glass.capacity_volume = '400'
print(glass)  
#> Glass(capacity_volume=400.0, occupied_volume=100.0)
```